# Common C idiom for keeping track of where errors occur

Tags: c, error-handling

I have an assignment where I need to read a certain number of `Foo`s from a file. In case the data inside the file is ill-formed for one of the `Foo`s, what are some common ways to signal (to `stderr`, for example) exactly which of the `Foo`s should be corrected?

My code looks something like this:

```
Foo foos[50];
FILE *file = fopen(...);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foos); ++i)
{
    if (readFoo(&foos[i], file) != 1)
        break;
}
```

The `readFoo` function will return `1` if read is successful; if not, it will return a negative number and print an error to `stderr` which specifies what's wrong but doesn't say where the error is. How should I implement this (*cleanely*) so that I also tell the user the value of `i`?

In C++ I would do this with exceptions. In C I thought of doing something like this (`readFoo` would set `error` accordingly whenever something doesn't go right):

```
/* These go in a source file */
const char *error = NULL;
const char error1[] = "Error 1 occurred.";
const char error2[] = "Error 2 occurred."; 

const char *getLastError() {
    return error;
}
```

What other ways are there to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clean" way to do this is to do the error reporting at the call site.  That is, do something like:

```
if( readFoo( foos + i, file, errbuf, errbuf_size ) != 1 ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "%d: %s\n", i, errbuf );
    ...    
}
```

That is, have readFoo populate a buffer with the error message rather than writing it to stderr.

Answer (score 2):

A well-known idiom in Unix-like operating systems is [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html), where a system call would return `-1` on error and set global variable to specify particular error type. Since this did not play well with multiple threads, the original idea was subverted for `errno` to be defined as a call to a function that retrieves per-thread error code.

Then, [POSIX threads API](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) went the other way to return zero on success, and error code on failure. This, in my opinion, is a preferred way of error reporting for user-land code, and I suggest following that.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C provides [`errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) to distinguish errors.  You can do the same, if you'd like.  It looks like you already have a loop and know what `i` is, though.  Can't you just do:

```
if (readFoo(&foos[i], file) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Read error on foo #%d\n", i);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Of course I can, but I'd like the message to look something like "Foo #2: Incorrect value", instead of "Incorrect value (Foo #2)". :) (`readFoo` will print the description of the message before I print the value of `i`.)

Comment: You'd need to modify `readFoo` to do that.  If that's an acceptable option, you could pass it `i`, store `i` in a global that `readFoo` can see, or keep a static variable in `readFoo` that counts the number of times it's been called.

Comment: That's less than ideal; `readFoo` should care that I'm reading multiple `Foo`s. :)

Comment: Well, if you just change `readFoo` to not print anything out, you can do all the error printing in the caller.  You can even use `perror(3)` to automatically turn `errno` into a human readable string.